When using pip install and pip uninstall, is the package name always the same?
For example, when installing the requests package:
pip install requests

Do you use always the same name when uninstalling it?
pip uninstall requests

The following three cases can be disregarded：

Version specification:

For example, if you want to install a specific version, you would use something like pip install requests==2.25.1, but for uninstalling, simply pip uninstall requests will work.


Dependencies:

pip uninstall only removes the target package, so any dependent packages may remain. If you want to remove these dependencies as well, you’ll need to check the dependencies and uninstall them individually.


The extras option during installation:

When using pip install package[extra] to install with additional features, you should uninstall the package without specifying the extra part. Instead, execute the uninstall command with only the base package name.




I can't think of a case where it would be different...is this just curiosity, or do you have a specific programming problem?

No I don't. But is it technically possible?

pip normalizes package names so it replaces umlauts with ASCII letters and replaces dots, minuses and underscores with a single minus. So you can install CT3 and uninstall ct3; install m_Librarian and uninstall m-librarian.


1.Version specification:

pip uninstall requests will uninstall all installed versions of requests

2.Dependencies:

You can use pip-autoremove to clean up the dependency, pip uninstall does not remove dependencies since the dependencies maybe needed by another package.

3.The extras option during installation:

There are also a lot of options in pip uninstall, you can check it by pip uninstall -help


When using pip install and pip uninstall, is the package name always the same?

Yes, they are always the same.

My question is it's technically possible to change the package name for installation and uninstallation.

No.

Even if you are the maintainer of a package, after you install the package named "old-package", you changed the package name to "new-package", you still need to use command pip uninstall old-package not pip uninstall new-package to uninstall it. Since they
are treated as separate packages by pip.

Some package do have a Aliased name, such as pillow and PIL, TensorFlow and tensorflow-gpu, but you still need to use same name to uninstall it. example:


pip install pillow
pip uninstall PIL    # Fails, since PIL is not installed


I meant that "the three cases are different package name for installation and uninstallation, so they can be disregarded in my question".
My question is it's technically possible to change the package name  for installation and uninstallation.

@Mat Watershed I see, I'll update my answer later.

@Mat Watershed If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted and upvoting it to acknowledge the effort. Thank you!

Is there a chance it will be installed under a different name during installation? For example, when installing the package abc, could it end up being installed as ABC instead?

@Mat Watershed It won't be installed under a different name during installation.
